# Access spring bean in Quartz job

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cron, quartz-scheduler

I had looked into most of the post on SO but none of this really helped. I am getting the NPE while accessing the DAO using spring bean.

My Scheduler

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class JobSchedulerImpl implements IJobScheduler {
    Scheduler scheduler;
    Trigger trigger;
    JobDetail job;

    public JobSchedulerImpl() {
    super();
    try {
        scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        logger.error("Exception while starting the scheduler :{} ", e.getMessage());
    }
}
@Override
public void runWeekly(String whichDay, String userName) throws Exception {
    //whichDay = whichDay.substring(0, 3);
    //String cornJobExpression = "0 07 16 ? * " + whichDay + " *";
    logger.info("Running Weekly Job");
    String cornJobExpression = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *";
    job = JobBuilder.newJob(RunWeeklyJob.class).withDescription("runWeeklyJob_" + userName)
            .withIdentity(userName, "group_runWeekly").build();
    trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("runWeeklyTrigger_" + userName, "group_runWeekly")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cornJobExpression)).startNow().build();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

     } 
}
```

Job Class

```
public class RunWeeklyJob implements Job {

public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RunWeeklyJob.class);

@Autowired
private IRunReport  report;

@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    //SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    JobDetail jobdetails = context.getJobDetail();
    JobKey jobKey = jobdetails.getKey();
    String name = jobKey.getName();
    report.getReport();
    logger.info("Context : {}", context.toString());

   }
}
```

Report Interface

```
public interface IRunReport {
public void getReport();
}
```

Implementation

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class RunReport implements IRunReport{
@Autowired
private IGenericCRUDDao genericDao;
public void getReport()
{
    System.out.println("genericDao" + genericDao);
    User userObj = genericDao.getEntityById(User.class, 1);
    System.out.println("userObj : " + userObj);
}
```

test case

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")
public class RunReportTest {
@Autowired
IJobScheduler jobScheduler;

@Test
public void test_A_AddClients() throws Exception {
    jobScheduler.runWeekly("MONDAY", "Santosh");
    Thread.sleep(70000);
}
}
```

I am getting the NPE while accessing the spring bean genericDao while running the scheduled job. I tried `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);` and other suggested answers on SO but no luck. Can someone help on where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was spring security was not allowing me to inject the bean outside the web context. Once I setup the permission it works as expected.

The interesting things that none of exception gives any clue about security related message.

Answer (score 0):

Check if specify the package scan component in your configuration.
Ex:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.here" />
```

Spring reads it to scan for annotations.